# Converting tuple to int

Tags: python, sqlite, tuples

I am new in Python and trying to convert tuple to int value, so I can do some math with it. I have got tuple form sqlite database.

```
for i in range(0,count):
    c.execute("SELECT small FROM sku")
    x = c.fetchall()
    small = int(x[i])
    print(small)
```

When I execute I have got the error message:

```
small = int(x[i])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'
```

Thank you

Comment: You want `x[i][0]`. Each row in the result is a tuple of all the columns.

Comment: I wonder why you are executing the same query `count` times - why not just loop over the results of a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite will return a list of tuples, each tuple representing a queried row as explained [here](https://pynative.com/python-cursor-fetchall-fetchmany-fetchone-to-read-rows-from-table/).

`x[i]` will be of type `tuple`

`x[i][j]` is what you want to do, as it will index individual elements in each tuple, where `j` is some index